# Could someone please explain how shifting is used in this code?

Tags: java, python, bit-manipulation

I'm solving sample problems while simultaneously trying to learn Python %\ ... but the problem book I got has problems and solutions in Java, so I'm trying to convert back and forth between the two languages. I just learned how bit shifting works and I've been staring at this code trying to figure out what exactly is going on here on line 5 (and 8) ... I tried writing down some examples just going through the code line by line but for some reason it's still not entirely obvious  to me ...
Could someone please clarify?

Also, it's really strange to me that `str.charAt(i)` returns a character, as far as I understand, and you can then proceed to subtract it from another character like numbers ... Is applying `int` to a character the same as `ord()` in Python?

Problem: Implement an algorithm to determine is a string has all unique characters.

Solution (in the case with only characters a-z):

```
1    boolean isUniqueChars(String str){
2       int checker = 0
3       for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
4          int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
5          if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0){
6             return false;
7          }
8          checker |= (1 << val);
9       }
10      return true;
11   }
```

Comment: In Java, characters are integer 16-bit unsigned types and `char - char -> int` (being the integer difference between the two [usually codepoints in the BMP]). In the case of Java there is no "int applied". It should not be surprising that `str.charAt(i)` returns a character because 1) what else would it return? and 2) it's documented to do so.

Comment: @user2864740, oh, I see. It wasn't str.charAt(i) returning a char that was confusing :) it was the following operation. But that part makes sense now. What is achieved by shifting 1 by the difference still eludes me tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  This code will really only work if `str` has only lower case letters in it.

`checker`  is a 32-bit integer, and you're using 26 of the 32 bits to record the presence of a particular letter in `str`.  So bit 0 will be used to record the presence of `a`, bit 1 will be used to record  the presence of `b`, and so on up to bit 25, which will be used to record the presence of `z`.

The basic algorithm is to work through `str`, character by character.  For each character, find the corresponding bit in `checker`.  If it's already been set, this character must be occurring for the second time - so we can stop processing and return `false`.  Otherwise, set that bit.

If you get to the end of the string without finding any duplicate characters, then return `true`.

The magic is in the following steps.

- Subtracting `'a'` from each character converts it to a number from 0 to 25.
- The symbol `<<` is the "left shift" operator, which moves a bit pattern a number of bits to the left.  The result of this is that `1 << val` is the place value of a particular bit (1, 2, 4, 8 etc).
- The symbol `&` does a binary AND, so the expression `checker & (1 << val)` will be 0 if bit `val` is cleared, or equal to `1 << val` if it is set.
- The symbol `|=` does a binary OR, and assigns the result to the variable on the left.  So the expression `checker |= (1 << val)` sets bit `val`.

Comment: So simple in retrospect... But why is this more efficient than using a boolean array, like in example shmosel gave?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm not even sure that it _would_ be faster than using a boolean array, although obviously it uses up less memory.  Either way, I certainly wouldn't ever program this way myself, more because of its lack of readability than anything else.

Comment: it's actually not obvious to me >.> ... is it because we're using an int instead of an array? <.< ... and why do you say it's not reliable?

Comment: An array of 26 booleans will take 26 bytes, whereas an int will take 4.  It's probably not especially important, unless you're programming for embedded systems or some other environment where every byte matters.  And I didn't say it's not reliable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, read that wrong >.< ... And I'm just reading this book on how to ace a programming interview +.+ ... so I guess they'll want me to optimize everything as much as possible, and that's why the book shows to do it that way. Thanks for all the explaining. I clearly have ways to go %\

Comment: Just a tip then - optimising for memory use or optimising for speed isn't always the best thing to do.  In many cases, optimising for the "big three" of readability, maintainability and testability is more appropriate.  It may pay to remember that in your interview, if you're going to be asked questions on it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try a simpler variation:

```
boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
    boolean[] seen = new boolean[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        // convert char to 0-based offset
        int index = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
        if (seen[index]) {
            // this char was seen already
            return false;
        }
        seen[index] = true;
    }
    // no duplicates found
    return true;
}
```

Pretty straighforward, right? We create a boolean array, using the character offset as an index, and check each character in the string to see if we've come across it yet. The code you posted uses the same logic, but with a more efficient bit set instead.

`(1 << val)` turns `val` into a bit index. `checker & (1 << val)` filters out other indexes so we can check just this one. `(checker & (1 << val)) > 0` checks if there's any value at the index. `checker |= (1 << val)` turns the bit on at the index. All of the other logic is identical.

Comment: That's the exact first solution the book uses :D Predefine an array with all values being false, then upon encountering a letter, change the slot corresponding to its ascii code to "true". But then it shows how to make it more efficient by converting to bits, and that's where they lost me. So it's literally the same concept then.

Answer (score 2):

First, the code will only work reliably if the input string contains letters 'a' to 'z'.

The variable checker is a 32 bit int.  Each bit in checker is used as a flag to indicate the presence of one of the 26 letters 'a' to 'z'.

The line

```
int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
```

converts the character stored at str index i into an integer stored in val, by subtracting the value of character 'a' so.  Yes I think pascal has the Ord('') function which does the same.

```
a = 0
b = 1
c = 2
etc
etc
etc
z = 25
```

the code

```
(1 << val)
```

shifts val into the appropriate value for its bit position,

so

```
a = 0 = 1
b = 1 = 2
c = 2 = 4
d = 3 = 8
etc
etc
z = 25 = 33554432

if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0)
```

determines if the bit is already set in checker, indicating a duplicate character.  If so the function returns false.

else

```
checker |= (1 << val)
```

sets the bit in checker via a binary OR and then loops round again.